# resetting jquery-chosen with default value

Tags: angularjs, jquery-chosen

how to reset `jquery-chosen` that has a default value. After reset, the default value should be the default selected value.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on your question

Comment: Do you mean that you have a set of selected values by default, and you want to be able to reset the Chosen UI to this default selection?